# Is there a way to force the navigation component to recreate a fragment when the bottom navigation is reselected

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

So basically, I have a bottom navigation using the Navigation component for Android. I need to refresh my fragment when reselecting the bottom navigation but when I reselect the item in the bottom nav, it keeps the state of the fragment the same. Is it possible to use the navcontroller to force the fragment to refresh?

Comment: Why isn't your fragment observing your data changes already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback and when reselected just call the function again which is fetchingData() and set it to UI.

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to help you with the exact answer.